# How to install/Store NuGet Packages inside the Visual Studio Project's folder?

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have already read [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376313/setting-up-a-common-nuget-packages-folder-for-all-solutions-when-some-projects-a) but the provided answers do not resolve my issue.

I need to put all the required NuGet packages by a project inside its own folder instead of installing it to the common user directory. I need to do this so that I can put the NuGet packages under **version control** to make them available on other systems because some PCs cannot get the required NuGet packages from the internet.

I have already tried to put a `nuget.config` file inside the solution directory (as shown below in the screenshot)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

[image]

...but even after doing that, when I install a new NuGet Package, the files are extracted to the common directory (i.e. `C:\Users\TestUser\.nuget\packages\knockoutjs\3.5.1`).

**QUESTION:** How can I set the extraction/installation of NuGet Packages to the project directory?
[image]

Comment: You can use a shared folder and put the packages there, and then make them available by adding folder's path to your %appdata%\Nuget\Nuget.config file or by adding a Nuget.config file to the solution.

Comment: @McNets: Unfortunately, a folder cannot be shared. I need to put the packages in the Git version control.

Comment: Then try to copy them from their original location: `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` and add a nuget.config file to the solution too.

Comment: @McNets Already doing that but it needs a lot of manual copying. Everytime a new NuGet package is installed, it needs to be copied to the folder manually. And, dependencies make it further complicated.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47862893/3270427) helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should move the nuget.config to the same directory as the solution and restart Visual Studio.